# ACS live id logout redirecting to msn.com

Tags: azure, acs

I have a custom login where i get my app authenticated using windows live id authentication ACS.

i am able to do proper login but there is a problem with logout. i get

https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignout1.0

logout link after de-serializing the ACS json file. but after navigating this it redirects me to msn.com site. how to redirect to my project Default.aspx page. i have a asp.net application. i also tried below code:

```
string cookieName = "FedAuth";             

if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains(Server.UrlEncode(cookieName)))
{
    var cookie = newHttpCookie(Server.UrlEncode(cookieName));
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}

WSFederationAuthenticationModule fam = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;

try
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
}
finally
{
    fam.SignOut(true);
}

string reply = fam.Realm + "default.aspx";

// Initiate a Federated sign out request to the STS.SignOutRequestMessage

signOutRequest = newSignOutRequestMessage(newUri(fam.Issuer), reply);
string logoutUrl = signOutRequest.WriteQueryString();
Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
```

but it didnt work. it logs out and stops to a page called as signout. After logout i want to redirect to my project page.

Comment: I think that currently you can't redirect your user back to your app. The only way I found possible to do so is by directly using the LIVE SDK.

Comment: Using Live id SDK as suggested by @**astaykov** works properly. but you get to click only sign in and signout links which is generated by the IFrame there. But in my case i want live id authentication site navigation on click of a live id msn logo. Hence i was going for ACS as it gives you a sign-in link. Also there is a overhead for registering your App in live id authentication SDK.

Comment: Azure Team reply..Hi,
                We were able to find out the following from the Azure Product Development team:
 
“Windows Live ID + ACS does not support redirecting users back to an ACS relying party web site upon Live ID sign out. “
 
So it is by design that for a clean logout the user will be redirected back to the Live ID sign out.